# How can I +1 a URL on Google+, when I didn't find it with Google?

Tags: google-plus-1

There's a site I'd like to +1 on Google+, but I have it in my bookmarks, and didn't find it by searching. How can I add the link to the "+1" section on my profile?

Of course, I could search on Google until I find the site, but in general, I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the website hasn't provided you a way of adding it's site to your +1 Tabs, you can install [this Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ppjihganhojelngokopdocghcngoapfd?hl=en).  It will add the current site you are on to your +1 Tab.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install the [+1 Plus One Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bkeiokdfjgnaglohebonlmpimnpinahd) for Google Chrome (this extension appears to only need access to your browsing history while others want access to all your data)
2. Open up the site from your bookmarks
3. Click on the +1 icon on the toolbar (you'll find this next to the wrench)
4. Click the **+1** button to confirm

The +1 of the webpage you're looking at will now appear in the +1 tab of your Google Plus profile.

Comment: Both posted extensions here do only access the browsing history.

Answer (score 4):

For a non-Chrome solution there is the [Google Plus One Bookmarklet](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-plus-one-bookmarklet/19474/) which should work in any modern browser.